# R: importing multiple files

Tags: r, import

I have data that is save with .log extension. The content of the file looks like:

```
Trajectory Log File
Date: Sun Mar 04 15:32:29 2018


Nr of Trajectories: 91
Trajectory-Mode: ON
Average Slope (Degrees): 28.05 / 51.99 / 64.83

Filename: test_tschamut_Pos1.xml

Z-offset: 1.32000
Rock Position X: 696621.38
Rock Position Y: 167730.02
Rock Position Z: 1679.6400

Friction:
Overall Type: Medium

               t (s)               x (m)               y (m)               z (m)               p0 ()               p1 ()               p2 ()               p3 ()          vx (m s-1)          vy (m s-1)          vz (m s-1)        wx (rot s-1)        wy (rot s-1)        wz (rot s-1)           Etot (kJ)           Ekin (kJ)      Ekintrans (kJ)        Ekinrot (kJ)              zt (m)             Fv (kN)             Fh (kN)        Slippage (m)      mu_s (N s m-1)       v_res (m s-1)     w_res (rot s-1)           JumpH (m)        ProjDist (m)               Jc ()           JH_Jc (m)              SD (m)
               0.000          696621.380          167730.020            1680.960               1.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000            1192.526               0.000               0.000               0.000            1677.754               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.350               0.000               0.000               3.206               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
               0.010          696621.380          167730.020            1680.959               1.000               0.000              -0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000              -0.098               0.000               0.000               0.000            1192.526               0.010               0.010               0.000            1677.754               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.350               0.098               0.000               3.205               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
               0.020          696621.380          167730.020            1680.958               1.000               0.000              -0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000              -0.196               0.000               0.000               0.000            1192.526               0.039               0.039               0.000            1677.754               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.350               0.196               0.000               3.204               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
               0.040          696621.380          167730.020            1680.952               1.000               0.000              -0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000              -0.392               0.000               0.000               0.000            1192.526               0.158               0.158               0.000            1677.754               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.350               0.392               0.000               3.198               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
               0.060          696621.380          167730.020            1680.942               1.000               0.000              -0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000              -0.589               0.000               0.000               0.000            1192.526               0.355               0.355               0.000            1677.754               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.350               0.589               0.000               3.188               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
               0.080          696621.380          167730.020            1680.929               1.000               0.000              -0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000              -0.785               0.000               0.000               0.000            1192.526               0.631               0.631               0.000            1677.754               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.350               0.785               0.000               3.175               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
               0.110          696621.380          167730.020            1680.901               1.000               0.000              -0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000              -1.079               0.000               0.000               0.000            1192.526               1.193               1.193               0.000            1677.754               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.350               1.079               0.000               3.147               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
               0.130          696621.380          167730.020            1680.877               1.000               0.000              -0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000              -1.275               0.000               0.000               0.000            1192.526               1.666               1.666               0.000            1677.754               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.350               1.275               0.000               3.123               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
               0.150          696621.380          167730.020            1680.850               1.000               0.000              -0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000              -1.472               0.000               0.000               0.000            1192.526               2.218               2.218               0.000            1677.754               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.350               1.472               0.000               3.096               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
               0.160          696621.380          167730.020            1680.834               1.000               0.000              -0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000              -1.570               0.000               0.000               0.000            1192.526               2.523               2.523               0.000            1677.754               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.350               1.570               0.000               3.080               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
               0.180
```

**How can i import this data format in R ?
Is it possible to import many files of this format at the same time?**

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the tabular part using `read.table` or `read.fwf` with `skip=N` (where N is the number of lines before table's header). Then you can read the first `N` lines with `readLines` and extract the parts you need.

For exporting many files with the same format, I suggest you start with writing a function combining all the steps, something like this:

```
read.log <- function(filename){
   first <- readLines(filename, 10)
   date <- sub("Date: ", "", first[2]) # get date from second row
   date <- as.POSIXct(date, format="?strptime") # convert to date
   # use ?strptime to see how to specify date format
   # .... likewise for other pieces eg. nr. of trajectories
   second <- read.table(filename, skip = 10) # some other no. instead of 10
   R <- list(data=second, date=date, otherstuff = otherstuff, ...)
   # return as a list 
   R
   }
```

Now you can use this function to read in any file, or apply it to a list of file names (using `lapply` or a `for` loop).

Comment: that works, thanks! Is there a way how to add multiple file of the same format. I have 90 of these and would like to avoid to repeat the command 90 times...

Comment: one way: `lapply(dir("mylogs", full.names=TRUE), read.log)`  (presuming that `read.log` takes a file name and returns the data, and your log files are in a subfolder called "mylogs"